# Bloquear download de arquivo via script PHP

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, segurança

Olá, estou com problema com download de alguns arquivos. Suspeito que alguém da equipe  está 'inputando' um script php que faça download de arquivos do servidor (como por exemplo configurações de bd em produção).

Gostaria de saber se é possível bloquear o download via script. Já bloqueei o acesso direto pela url (http://meuserver/path/file.php) e as permissões estão para leitura somente ao usuário do apache. No entanto, quando executo o código abaixo, consigo fazer o download do arquivo e visualizar seu conteúdo.

Segue exemplo de código que desejo inibir:

```
$arquivo = "path/file.php";
header("Content-Type: " . $tipo); 
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($arquivo)); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($arquivo));
```

Já fiz diversas pesquisas e só encontrei como bloquear o acesso direto, porém com o código acima é possível baixar o arquivo.

Ps: atualmente preciso bloquear um único arquivo.

Comment: Já respondi uma pergunta sobre isso aqui no site. Foi em Laravel, mas o exemplo se aplica ao PHP. Você pode usar autenticação ou até CAPTCHA pra avacalhar quem tá te zoando.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi: estão conseguindo baixar o seu script PHP? Agora fiquei na dúvida

Comment: Fiz alguns testes, mas o PHP não vem com o script aberto, ele vem apenas com os echos que tem dentro dele, ou seja, o usuário não consegue baixar o código em si.

Comment: Só vem o html, seria uma enorme falha se vem o php

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem sua pergunta, você está com medo que alguém da sua equipe esteja intencionalmente colocando brechas de segurança na sua aplicação que permitam acesso externo à informações sigilosas.
Se for este o caso tem pouco o que pode ser feito a nível de código. Você pode tentar proteger o arquivo ou informação de alguma forma, mas o sujeito pode disponibilizar de outra. O que você precisa é melhorar seu processo de desenvolvimento, revisão e deploy e encontrar quem está fazendo isso, caso esteja mesmo acontecendo, e removê-la da equipe. Dependendo do tamanho da equipe, passe a fazer revisão de tudo que ela produzir antes de colocar no ar, desta forma você consegue achar o problema.

Por padrão, quando você coloca a aplicação no ar o código fonte só será disponível para download se você não configurar apropriadamente o módulo php no webserver ou se alguma falha acontecer, que em alguns casos faz com que o webserver devolva o fonte.
Geralmente isso é resolvido não deixando o código php na pasta pública (/var/www/html, por exemplo).